# Mongoose: updating array in document not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update an array in document by adding object if it doesn't exist, and replacing the object in array otherwise. But nothing ($push, $addToSet) except the $set parameter does anything, and $set works as expected - overwrites the whole array.
My mongoose schema:

```
var cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   mail: String,
   items: Array
});
```

The post request handler:

```
app.post('/addToCart', function(req, res) {
var request = req.body;
Cart.findOneAndUpdate({
        "mail": request.mail
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            "items": request.item
        }
    }, {
        upsert: true
    },
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
);
    res.send(true);
});
```

The data that I'm sending from the client:

```
{  
"mail":"test@gmail.com",
"item":{  
      "_id":"59da78db7e9e0433280578ec",
      "manufacturer":"Schecter",
      "referenceNo":"Daemon-412",
      "type":"Gitare",
      "image":"images/ba9727909d6c3c26412341907e7e12041507489988265.jpeg",
      "__v":0,
      "subcategories":[  
          "Elektricne"
      ]
}
}
```

***EDIT:***

I also get this log when I trigger 'addToCart' request:

```
{ MongoError: The field 'items' must be an array but is of type object in 
document {_id: ObjectId('5a19ae2884d236048c8c91e2')}
```

Comment: what is the content of `item`?

Comment: The json object at the bottom of the original post

Comment: see the update.

Comment: Do you have a model of "item"? or is it just an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison in $addToSet would succeeded **only** if the existing document has the exact same fields and values, and the fields are in the same order. Otherwise the operator will fail.

So in your case, request.item always need to be exactly the same.

I would recommend creating a model of "item". Then, your cart schema would be like:

```
var cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   mail: String,
   items: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'item',
    }],
});
```

And let MongoDB determine if the item exist.

Answer (score 0):

this should work you just need to implement `objectExits` function that test if the item is that one you're looking for :

```
Cart.findOne({ "mail": request.mail })
    .exec()
    .then(cart => {
        var replaced = cart.items.some((item, i) => {
            if (item._id == request.item._id)) {
                cart.items[i] = request.item;
                return true;
            }
        })
        if (!replaced) {
            cart.items.push(request.item);
        }
        cart.save();
        return cart;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```